# LIB and DLL difference

Tags: vb6

What is the difference between a LIB and DLL? I have read plenty of posts on here about it and there are some good, clear answers however I am writing to ask for clarity on one matter.

Is it better to use a LIB (static link library) when there is only one user e.g. for a administration application client installed locally on the PC? and is it better to use a DLL (Dynamic link library) when there are multiple concurrent users accessing a classic asp application that uses vb6 classes?

Comment: VB6 is only able to create dynamic ActiveX libraries (unless exposed to mad skillz, after which it's also able to create native dynamic libraries). But it's not able to create static libraries. So why tagged as VB6?

Comment: When I compile my VB6 project; a LIB file and a DLL file is producted.

Answer (score 4):

A LIB file generally corresponds to a static library, which means that all of the library code that your application uses is compiled directly into your application.

A DLL file represents a dynamic library that your application links to, and then when you want to use code from the library, you call into it dynamically while your application is running.

Of course, you'll frequently see a LIB file for a dynamically-linked library as well. That file contains "stubs" that the linker uses to implicitly link to the DLL.

The obvious benefit of a DLL (dynamic linking) is that one DLL with common functionality can be shared with multiple applications that use that same functionality. Bug fixes can be made in a single place, and only one component has to be updated in order for all of the apps to take advantage of those fixes.

If you only have a single application that uses your code, there's little reason to put it into a DLL. Multiple users on multiple computers are going to have to have their own copy of the DLL anyway, so there will be no code sharing going on in that situation.

All of that said, I have no idea what this question has to do with VB 6. To my knowledge, you can only use it to create ActiveX DLLs (which have a different use case) and it can't create static libraries at all.

Comment: The reason I added the VB6 category is because it is a VB6 application, but perhaps a more general category would have been better.  The VB6 application generates a .LIB and .DLL when compiled.  I register the .dll, but not the .lib and the application works without any errors.  Why don't I have to register the .LIB?

Comment: The LIB file is part of the compile and link (make) process.  You never use the LIB at runtime and never deploy it.  Most programs cannot use the LIB file, and I don't know of any practical way for a VB program to do so.  With some hacking you might make a regular DLL based on the LIB but there's no advantage.  Just leave it be.

Comment: I have inherited a number of VB6 applications (I come from a Java background).  It appears that with one of the other VB6 applications; a VB6 LIB file is actually registered and used by a classic asp application.  I could be wrong though.